# What is the nice FONT?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I really like this font, but I could not figure out what's the name of it.

`It looks like garamond and Linux Libertine.`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, the source is from: http://www.foreignaffairs.com/articles/141071/lukas-kaelin/borderline-behavior. But I could not print it out in PDF or copy the text to `Word`.

Comment: According to the CSS it is `BentonSansCond` and `WilliamsCaslonText`.

Comment: So they are commercial fonts and not available in `Latex`

Comment: Yes, they are commercial. No, they are available LaTeX through `fontspec` in XeLaTeX.

Comment: You could try `librecaslon` for the Caslon though I don't know how similar it is.